# In ElasticSearch(Nest), Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using Nest Client to communicate with ElasticSearch.

When i trying to index child type it is giving me error in the heading. I have already set this attribute on Parent Type :  [ElasticType(Name ="item", IdProperty = "id")]. This should tell elastic type about id field.

Below is the query made by nest with error info.

```
{StatusCode: 400, 
    Method: PUT, 
    Url: http://localhost:9200/itemindex/inventory/15894?routing=15894&parent=15894, 
    Request: {
  "itemId": 15894,
  "inventories": [
    {
      "storeId": 20693,
      "inventoryCount": 40
    }
]
}

Response: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured"},"status":400}}
```

When i am using this query directly with sense. It is successfully inserting and updating data. But not when i try with Nest.

Please suggest? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Could any one explain the reason of this error?

Comment: Any solution..?

Comment: The issue was due Nest 1.7 not compatible 2.0.x ElasticSearch. It was mentioned by @Rob in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your index mapping, but looks like you forgot to specify parent when defining mapping for child document.

This is how you can do this with NEST 2.0.0-alpha1.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var response = client.CreateIndex(indexName, d => d
    .Mappings(map => map
        .Map<Parent>(m => m.AutoMap())
        .Map<Child>(m => m.AutoMap().Parent<Parent>())));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have already added this but don't what wrong .... SearchClient.Map<Child>( x => x.MapFromAttributes().SetParent<Parent>() );

Comment: NEST 1.x isn't compatible with ES 2.x, so this could be the issue here.

Comment: Nest latest version is 1.7 and should be compatible with elasticsearch 2.x. am i right.

Comment: Latest version of NEST is 2.0.0-alpha1 https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/2.0.0-alpha1. 1.7 is not compatible with ES 2.x.